# Ajax call replaces the whole content

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a form and submit button. Normally when the submit action is taken it returns to a new page and not update the partial view. I use ajax call in jquery live function but it still does replace the whole content instead of returning partial view with provided model. The following is my code in _detailfile.cshtml. The application uploads the file but replaces the whole content.

```
<div id="trainingFileDiv" style="overflow: auto; height: 470px;">
 <table class="fileTable">
                @foreach (var training in Model.TrainingList)
                {
                    using (Html.BeginForm("fileForm", "Home/TempUpload", new { employeeId = Model.Id, trainId= @training.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                    {
                        if (training.TrainingFile != null)
                        {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                        }

                        else
                        {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="view_detail_label" style="width: 250px;">
                            @training.Name.Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input  type="file" name="@training.Id"/>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                     <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Yükle" /></td>

                     </tr>
                        }

                    }

                }
            </table>
</div>
```

Following is my script to only update the div file but it does not work.

```
 $("fileForm").live("submit",  function (event) {


         if (form.valid()) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: this.action,
                 type: this.method,
                 data: $(this).serialize(),
                 success: function (result) {
                     $('#trainingFileDiv').html(result);
                 }
             });
         }

         event.preventDefault();
     });
```

This is another code I found on the net and it does not update the div but all content.

```
$(function () {
    $('fileForm').submit(function () {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('#trainingFileDiv').html(result);
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

What am i missing here?
Thank you for your help

**EDIT1**
When the partial view is returned from controller , I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` fileForm:7

**EDIT2** function to ajaxify all forms. I get the error in edit1

```
  $(function () {
         $('form').submit(function () {
             if ($(this).valid()) {
                 $.ajax({
                     url: this.action,
                     type: this.method,
                     data: $(this).serialize(),
                     success: function (result) {
                         $('#trainingFileDiv').append(result);
                     },
                 });//end of ajax call
             }//end of if

         });     });
```

**EDIT3** In the below code I have no errors but there are not any files in Request.You can see the controller code just below the function. But when I put either return true or false, the file is placed in Request object and sent to controller. But it replaces my all content on the return. What is wrong here?

```
$('form').submit(function (event) {

         if ($(this).valid()) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: this.action,
                 type: this.method,
                 data: $(this).serialize(),
                 success: function (result) {
                     $('#trainingFileDiv').html(result);
                 },
                 complete: function () {
                     console.log("Complete");
                 },
                 error: function () {
                     console.log("Error");
                 }
             }); //end of ajax call
         } //end of if
         //return true;//if commented no error on jquery side but no files are passed to controlller
     });

  foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
            {
                string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
                string filename = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
                TrainingFile file = new TrainingFile();
                file.Name = filename;
                file.Path = path;



                var training = _work.TrainingRepository.GetSet().Where(a => a.EmployeeId == employeeId && a.Id == trainId).ToList().ElementAt(0);
                training.TrainingFile = file;
                training.FileId = file.Id;

                _work.TrainingFileRepository.Add(file);
                _work.TrainingFileRepository.Save();
                _work.TrainingRepository.UpdateAndSave(training);
                _work.TrainingRepository.Save();

                Request.Files[upload].SaveAs(Path.Combine(path, filename));
            }
```

Comment: I want to update the all table with the returned data because i return the same partial view the result content will be same with updatred version. What do you mean by file div?

Comment: Did you add reference to jQuery? For example <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script> this reference

Comment: Yes i did it in master page, my other partial views are using jquery and they are working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't have high enough rep to comment yet, although I am trying to get there.
To get the Form you can use $('form') if you only have one form on the page.
Otherwise dependent on the view engine you are using you might need to add some additional syntax to specify the Id of the form.

Like Darin Dimitrov suggested:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("fileForm", "Home/TempUpload", new { employeeId = Model.Id, trainId= @training.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "fileForm" }))
```

in Razor you need to add @ to the id so it would be like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("fileForm", "Home/TempUpload", 
new { employeeId = Model.Id, trainId= @training.Id }, FormMethod.Post, 
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @id = "fileForm" }))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#trainingFileDiv').html(result);// ovverides already existing html

$('#trainingFileDiv').append(result); //adds new result to existing html
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but this does not work still replaces the content.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong and returns no elements:

```
$('fileForm')
```

and of course you are attaching the submit handler to no elements.

You probably wanted to use an id selector to retrieve the form:

```
$('#fileForm')
```

Also don't forget to assign this `id` to your form:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("fileForm", "Home/TempUpload", new { employeeId = Model.Id, trainId= @training.Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "fileForm" }))
```

or if you wanted to AJAXify all forms on the page (or you had a single form) you could just use:

```
$('form')
```

Of course absolutely same remark stands for your `$("fileForm").live` selector. Also notice that the `.live` method is deprecated since long time ago and unless you are using a jQuery version from the prehistory you probably want to use the recommended [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did it as you say both with form and #fileform but I get the same error from the console. I want to ajaxify all forms. As I am using jquery 1.5 I can not use on function

Comment: If you want to AJAXify all forms then use `$('form')` selector. And if you want to do it in a *lively* manner use the `.delegate()` function, not the `.live()` which as I already said in my answer is completely obsolete.

Comment: I use second function without live on using '$('form')' selector, it gives me the same error

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: form is not defined  I get this error

Comment: You cannot possibly get this exception from `$('form')`. You are getting it somewhere else. Unfortunately it's hard to help without seeing your code.

Comment: I get it when i change it to delegate function using:
 $(document).delegate("form","submit", function (event)

Comment: Sorry, I really cannot help from the small fragments of code you are providing here. The following selector should work just fine: `$(document).delegate("form", "submit", function () { ... });`. Maybe you have some other issue. Providing an http://jsfiddle.net with your full code illustrating the problem would help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31670/discussion-between-eneramo-and-darin-dimitrov)

Comment: You seem to be attempting to POST a form containing a file input using AJAX. This is not possible and not supported. You cannot use AJAX to upload files. You will have to use some of the existing file upload plugins such as Uploadify or Blueimp File Upload if you want to implement such functionality. Alternatively, if your client browsers support the HTML 5 File API, you could use that to asynchronously upload files to the server. But with a simple `$.ajax` call you can forget about it.